# VBA Excel - Find strings in all sheets, and copy matching rows to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel file with many sheets. I would like to find a string in any cell of the existing sheets and copy it to a new "Results" sheet. I need to get the rows where many strings (about 50 different strings) are found and have those results in a separate row.

It would be GREAT if I can provide the set of strings to search, and that the "Results" sheet have a blank row between blocks of results (to differentiate blocks of found strings).

I've googled this already but found code that copy rows of matching strings, but they only search in 1 sheet, and I need to search in all existing sheets (Except the "Results" sheet, of course).

I will really appreciate very much your help!

Comment: This is not a site where you ask things to be coded for you.

Comment: Or you can post at least post codes of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `ProcessSheet` function that works on one sheet you can run it on every sheet with somethign like:

```
Dim Sh As WorkSheet
For Each Sh In Sheets
  If Sh.Name <> "Sheet not to process" Then ProcessSheet Sh
Next Sh
```

And modify your `ProcessSheet` so that every reference uses `Sh`, like this:

```
'without sheet reference
Cells(1, 2)
Range("A1")
'become
Sh.Cells(1, 2)
Sh.Range("A1")
```